# Spring Boot - Hazelcast Session implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I have Recently started working on Spring Boot. I came to know the feature called Hazelcast.

Can some one please explain me about how the Hazelcast can be used for accessing session and setting session attributes ?

Also it would be great if i can get the information about how the session will be managed.

BestRegards,
Hemal.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/springboot-http

Disclaimer: I wrote this example.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. it helped me.